# Is it possible to use a precompiled function in a new program?

Tags: c++

I'm coding a program with a function that makes compilations quite long as it needs its own library. I don't see myself changing this function as it does what I expect from it and I only call it incidentally. This is why I'd like to know if there is a way to compile it once and for all in something like a library, including this library in someway in my program so it can have access to this specific function. I was also thinking about coding it in a separated program and using system(commands) to run it but I was wondering if there was a neater way of doing it. Is there something?

Comment: What operating system?  What compiler?  Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Yes, that's what a **library** is for. Compile it, build a library, and whenever you need it, link to that library.

Comment: That's what libraries are for, yes!

Comment: @JohnZwinck Ubuntu, gcc, no IDE I'm coding in gEdit.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok thank you for the suggestion, once I compiled to a library do I still need to have the headers used in my library when compiling my final program?

Comment: @Liam - you need a header that contains a declaration for the function, so that code that calls it knows what its argument types and return type are. You don't need any of the headers that were used to build the library.